# how to write a css for the slide of swipe view?

Tags: html, css, swipe, swipeview

I am implementing a swipeview using [this](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).

my doubt is how should the **CSS** be.The **CSS** i implemented is as follows.

```
.swiper-threshold {
width:100%;
height:350px;
margin-top:40px;
text-align:left;
line-height:20px;
font-size: 15px;
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
}

.swiper-threshold .swiper-slide{
width:auto;
height:350px;
margin-top:2%;
margin-left:0;
padding-right:0%;
text-align:left;
line-height:20px;
font-size: 15px;
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
}
```

the sliding movement is from left to right.when it reaches the last slide.the movement reverses. 
when,I change `margin-left:0;` from 0 to say 5...as and when I slide the left space gets on adding up the last slide is seen for half of the screen.

but,when i give `margin-left:0;` all are stuck to the left margin.

**html coding:**

```
 <div id="swipe_body">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-threshold">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="swiper-wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SWIPER-SLIDE creation**

```
            var val = k+1;
            var superdiv = document.getElementById('swiper-wrapper');
            var newdiv =  mySwiper.createSlide('div');
            newdiv.append();
            var divIdName = 'swiper-slide'+val;
            console.log("div name: "+divIdName);
            newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
            newdiv.className="swiper-slide";
            superdiv.appendChild(newdiv);
            var cnt = '<div id="container'+val+'" class="container">values</div>';
            document.getElementById(divIdName).innerHTML=cnt;
            console.log("processsing parameter loop ");
```

what should i give such that n-number of swipes the slides should be the same position-middle of the screen.

please,guide me!